# Unable to connect Azure Function App with Database (using .net core 2.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1

**Please note (Environment):**
Function App: Version 2,
Target Framework: .Net Core 2.1

I am developing a Function App, that will work like Web Api. This Function App will return the data from database tables, also it'll manipulate files in Azure storage(Blob). But I am stuck as I am unable to create **ConnectionString** from **local.settings.json** file. Ideally the connection string should be created by default as I followed some tutorials & no where mentioned any extra steps to create default **connectionstring** value, just need to create it in **local.settings.json** file.

following is my **local.settings.json** file content:-

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "mycs": "data source=servername;initial catalog=dbname;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "mycs": "data source=servername;initial catalog=dbname;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

following is my HttpTrigger file:

```
    namespace my_api
    {
        public class myDataContext : DbContext
        {
            public myDataContext() : base(GetConnectionString()) { }
            private static string GetConnectionString()
            {

                const string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                const string metadata = @"res://*/MYDB.csdl|res://*/MYDB.ssdl|res://*/MYDB.msl";
                try
                {
                    string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycs"].ToString();


                    // Initialize the connection string builder for the
                    // underlying provider.
                    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

                    // Set the properties for the data source.
                    //sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                    sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

                    // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
                    string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

                    // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
                    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

                    //Set the provider name.
                    entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

                    // Set the provider-specific connection string.
                    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

                    // Set the Metadata location.
                    entityBuilder.Metadata = metadata;

                    return entityBuilder.ConnectionString;
                }
                catch { }

                var connectionstring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mycs");
                return connectionstring;
            }

            public DbSet<flowerset> flowersets
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Following is the code for :

```
namespace my_api
```

{
    public static class helpService
    {
        [FunctionName("helpService_get")]
        public static async Task> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request helpService_get).");

```
        try {
            int page = 0;
            int pageSize = 20;

            myDataContext entity = new myDataContext();
            if (page == 0 && pageSize == 0)
            {
                return entity.helpsets.ToList();
            }
            if (pageSize <= 0) { pageSize = 20; }
            entity.helpsets.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception exx) {
            log.LogInformation("Exception changed (helpService_get): "+exx.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

}//End of Class
}//End of Namespace
```

I am getting following error on line  **entity.helpsets.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();**:

```
Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

Comment: According to your error, I think you do not install the package ```System.Data.SqlClient```. Could you please check if you have installed the package in your function project?

Comment: yes the package System.Data.SqlClient is installed & I am seeing this error as Function App 2.0 is .net core application where It seems that support for ADO.net is not available or may be I am not aware of other solution.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use `System.Data.SqlClient` to connect Azure SQL in Azure function V2.0. For example

1. Create an Azure Function with Visual Studio 2019
2. Install System.Data.SqlClient package(the version I sue is 4.5.1)
   [image]
3. Develop the function

local.settings.json file content

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "mycs": "Data Source="";Initial Catalog=DotNetAppSqlDb20190826105048_db;User Id="";Password="" "
  },

  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Code

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            try
            {
                var connectionstring = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:mycs"); ;



                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {


                    connection.Open();
                    log.LogInformation(" sql login success");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("select * from dbo.Todoes");

                    String sql = sb.ToString();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                log.LogInformation("{0} {1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup)
[image]

Comment: @user1400290 Is that OK for you? Do you have any other concern?